# Destiny drop outs

Tags: ps4, destiny

I'll be playing Destiny quite happily for a few hours, then all of a sudden, without any notice, I'll be kicked off and just bombarded with different error codes every time I try and attempt to rejoin the game: "fly", "cow", "centipede" and "peacock" just to name a few. This bombardment ensues for a good twenty minutes before I give up.

There is no consistency in the error codes, and upon researching them, (for the most part) the only help they provide is *"Try doing what you were doing beforehand. Otherwise, we might be doing some maintenance."* or *"Check your internet connection"* or even *"If your home network is behind a firewall, Destiny requires these ports to be open:"*

Yes, thanks Bungie. Your error codes are mildly amusing, yet still vague as ever.

I don't know what causes it, and the inconsistency of the error codes are no help whatsoever. I have tried reloading the game, resetting my modem, restarting the console, all to no avail.

Does anyone know what might cause these walls of errors?

Comment: Those are mostly just network connection error codes. There's a list on bungie.net that I can't find right now... Not sure why they present to the player a whole bunch of different names that have the same explanation though. The cause of the problem might be someone else on your connection suddenly watching netflix or doing torrents or something that causes an large change in your latency or throughput.

Comment: @Eben at first I thought the same, but after a few episodes I made sure no one was doing anything, all other PCs were off, no downloading or anything. Still no luck.

Comment: Bummer, 'cause that would be relatively easy to fix.

Comment: There were server issues on Saturday that probably caused this.  Around 2pm EST?  Lizard Squad claimed responsibility but the servers were back up within a half hour or so.

Comment: Unfortunately this is still occurring for me. @turbo

Comment: Hm I actually experience this yesterday, but only once.  I'd try posting on bungie.net if you haven't already.  Maybe someone there can get it to the right people to help you diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A drop in connection might be caused my numerous things. The most prominent reasons for loosing connections are, in my opinion:

- loss of packets resulting in a timeout on either end,
- the server being busy,
- the game world being full / overloaded,
- your connection being reset due to being afk or similar,
- an error on the server side, and
- the server or instance restarting.

In an ideal world, all error codes these events would produce would be able to tell you more about the problem you encountered. Unfortunately, the error messages are produced by the server who only has limited knowledge about you or your connection and the software running on your machine which has only limited knowledge about the server.

When you are disconnected actively by the server, usually because you time outed due to not issuing any controls for a period of time, the server can produce a very accurate message, hence you will get a notification that you are being returned to orbit. This is essentially also an error message but one where the server was sure what happened. The same happens with restarts of the instance you are in.

However, when you are disconnected because, for example, your ISP encountered some problems routing packages, the server does not know what happened. It only knows you are not responding and will drop the connection. The game on your end will struggle to reconnect and not be able as the server dropped the connection. However, it does not know why. It simply knows that it did not receive any packages and can't reconnect. But what happened? Did the server crash? Is maintenance being performed? Is the server busy or has blacklisted your IP? There is no way to be sure if the server does not also provide some feedback.

In an optimal system the server and client would work together to produce a global view on the problem and they could figure it out. Unfortunately, due to some constraints on load and connectivity, that is not going to happen. In a sub-optimal but still good scenario, the software will perform an analysis of causes and determine what is the most likely reason for your loss of connection and give you that feedback. This is why you might see different error codes. Another reason is that the software caches errors and shows you a different one every time in an attempt to give you more diverse feedback to increase the probability that one of them will fix your problem.